# does time complexity of if and if else is same or not?

Tags: performance, if-statement, time

I am confused about whether I should use only if and return functions, or if and else. What is the best approach? Please guide me.

I have tried searching for answers, but the time complexity of different approaches is complex for me to understand.

What is the best approach to handling nested if and else statements, other than using switch cases? Is the time complexity of switch cases the same as if and else?

Thank you for your help.